# Generate matrix of unique combination using 2 variables from a data frame r

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, permutation

I have a data frame as 
df<- as.data.frame(expand.grid(0:1, 0:4, 0:3,0:7, 2:7))
I want to get all unique combinations using 2 variables of the given 5 variables in the data frame df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct` function from `dplyr` package:

```
df <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(0:1, 0:4, 0:3,0:7, 2:7))    

library(dplyr)    
df %>% 
  distinct(Var1, Var2)
```

Also you have an option to keep the rest of your columns with `.keep_all = TRUE` parameter.

If you want to get all the possible combinations:

```
# Generate matrix with all combinations of variables
comb <- combn(names(df), 2)

# Generate a list with all unique values in your data.frame
apply(comb, 2, function(x) df %>% distinct_(.dots = x))
```

Comment: Thank you buddy :)

Comment: @DwaipayanDutta, you're welcome! This implementation is similar to `unique` but regarding to [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/distinct) it is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a function `f` (extracting unique couple) to each couple of columns:

```
f<-function(col,df)
{
   return(unique(df[,col]))
}

#All combinantions
comb_col<-combn(colnames(df),2)
```

Your output

```
apply(comb_col,2,f,df=df)
[[1]]
   Var1 Var2
1     0    0
2     1    0
3     0    1
4     1    1
5     0    2
6     1    2
7     0    3
8     1    3
9     0    4
10    1    4

[[2]]
   Var1 Var3
1     0    0
2     1    0
11    0    1
12    1    1
21    0    2
22    1    2
31    0    3
32    1    3
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I need to use all the combinations as 
Var 1 and Var 2 , Var 2 and Var 3 , Var 3 and Var4, Var 4 and Var 5
Var 1 and Var 5, Var 2 and var 5 and so on  with all the values of the variables